# Where is Madam MeowMeow's BowWow dog?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I can't leave the town and go towards the beach, or the small children stop me and tell me how terrible the Moblin attack was, and mot other directions require me to lift rocks, which I cannot do.

The woman in the BowWow house (Madam MeowMeow) is super distraught over her missing dog, and I would really like to help her (as I assume this is the next thing I have to do to advance the story).

Where did they take her dog?

Comment: good lord, its been YEARS. can you go into the woods\forest? Thats what memory says but like I already mentioned, I havent played that game in ages.

Comment: I can, but unless I am blind (which is entirely possible) I didn't see them there.

Comment: just out of curiosity - how far into the game is this??

Comment: @mbanzon Right after the first dungeon (Tail Cave).

Comment: @mbanzon Not very far at all, just after the first dungeon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

North of the village, in a cave near the Bottle Grotto Swamp, to the east of it I think.

> You need Bow Wow the Chain Chomp to eat the plants blocking your way to get to the inner swamp and dungeon 2 (Bottle Grotto).

Comment: [East](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Moblin_Cave), actually.

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes, that fits better with my memory.

Comment: Yes it is east of the dungeon in a cave with  baddies and a particularly easy boss